# Stash Repository/Project deletion failed and unable to add new users/groups in repositories

Tags: bitbucket-server

I have installed stash 3.2 and added the evaluation license for testing purpose. i created a project and created the repository. I was testing the various functionalities by deleting a repository and project which failed. I tried to add group to repo which also failed. seeing the below in log

2014-08-20 11:09:09,490 INFO [http-bio-17993 exec-2] admin @L9VJK8x669x260x0 gnwktx 10.178.23.278 "GET /projects/MON/repos/testing/settings HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.w.a.RepositoryAdminController Failed to resolve default branch. Cause: refs/heads/master is set as the default branch, but this branch does not exist

2014-08-20 11:18:04,549 INFO [http-bio-17993-exec-4] admin @L9VJK8x678x404x0 gnwktx 10.178.23.278 "GET /projects/MON/repos/testing/settings HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.w.a.RepositoryAdminController Failed to resolve default branch. Cause: refs/heads/master is set as the default branch, but this branch does not exist

i get the below pop up while trying to add group(permission) for a particular repo

Something went wrong while trying to serve your request. Try reloading the page.

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a default branch.Usualy master is the default branch but your repo does not have a master . You can do 2 things

1. Create a master branch
2. Set a default branch. You can do this in the repository settings. Also if you go into admin view into your repo , it will give you a direct link where you set this

Answer (score 0):

I'm the product manager for Stash. I was unable to reproduce this issue, but if it's still causing concern please don't hesitate to contact our [support team](http://support.atlassian.com).